# Changing color with geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, color, color-management

I have an instance called 'Eye' with two differents materials.
I need to be able to change the color of the material 'R white' with Geometry Nodes. In the image the white color of the fundus of the eye.

How can I change the color without comparing the index of each face?

[image: The eye]

Thanks for your help :)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

You can use "replace material" node for that.

Hope it helps. Have fun!

or this is also possible:

[image]

Comment: This way is very easy to use.
Thanks Chris !

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few ways of doing this ..  it would depend on what you want to expose to the user. Here, we put a color into a named attribute, depending on a mix-factor set in the GN interface:

[image]

.. and pick the color up in the eye-white material:

[image]

for a mix:

[image]

.. but you could set the colors in the GN interface, too, or leave the mix to the shader, store the color on a pre-existing attribute rather than creating one, set the mix to be between 2 image-textures..  all sorts.

Comment: Thanks Robin, for your solution!
:)